Computing the Groebner Basis takes a long time
I often need to compute the GroebnerBasis. Sometimes it takes a long time to respond. Sometimes changing a term to its reciprocal speeds up the computation, and sometimes modifying the elimination order helps. But there are times when nothing works, no matter what I try. For example, in this case, I would like to seek advice from everyone. Thank you.
GroebnerBasis[{(((a - d)/(q - p))/((q - p)/(b - c)))^-1 - t0, 
((d - c)/(d - p) (c - b)/(c - p))^-1 -  t1,
 (a - p)/(a - b) (b - p)/(b - c) -   t2,
 ((c - q)/(c - d) (d - q)/(d - a)) -   t3, 
((b - a)/(b - q) (a - d)/(a - q))^-1 - t4, 
       1 - (a - c)/(a - d)/((b - c)/(b - d)) - t5},
 {}, {a, b, c, d, p, q}] // Factor


Let me recommend you at least simplify your equations... all those ratios that also include x^-1 are awkward and confusing.  If you have (a/b)^-1, why not write b/a?

This is what I am trying, because I found that changing a term to its reciprocal and making the denominators of some terms the same can make the calculation easier.

You are eliminating 6 variables from 6 polynomials. I think the result will be empty, unless quotienting out the denominators somehow changes things.

Exactly why do you need GroebnerBasis? There may be alternatives.

@Somos The usual reason for an example like this is to implicitize a parametrized rational variety. Except in this specific example there seems to be one too many parameters.

You may be interested in "Comparison of implicitization methods" by Bastl (2005). It mentions how fast Mathematica is using an interpolation method.
